# If Else condition in mysql to check null

Tags: mysql

How should I make if condition in mysql `where time = null` then I want result in NO else YES?

```
SELECT
case when TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Event01.EndTime ,Event01.StartTime)) != NULL THEN
@Loss:='YES'
ELSE
@Loss:='NO'
END AS Loss
from Event01,(SELECT @Loss:= 0) AS Loss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query**

```
SET @Loss := 0;

SELECT
@Loss:= case when TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Event01.EndTime ,Event01.StartTime)) IS NOT NULL 
THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'NO' END
FROM Event01;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have to check NULL using is clause.

```
SELECT
case when TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Event01.EndTime ,Event01.StartTime)) is not NULL THEN
    'YES'
    ELSE
    'NO'
    END AS Loss
from Event01
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: No its not giving any display output like yes or no table's data of loss stays empty.

Comment: remove not and then run the query, tell me what is the output.

Comment: It is giving me answer in YES but still I cant get NO.But still thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  case when TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Event01.EndTime ,Event01.StartTime)) IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS Loss from Event01
```